# How to name a package module the same as a python or third party module

Tags: python, package

I have a `package1` with its `__init__.py` file inside and a file `logging.py` that takes care of the log necessities of the program. The problem is that I want to use the python **logging** module so when I try to import the logging module from `logging.py` I get:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'

This happens because the import statement is importing the `logging.py` file instead of the python logging module and trying to find the module inside it. I don't want to rename the file because I want to keep the naming convention I've established. Is there a way to keep the file name (importing it as `package1.logging`?) while being able to import the python logging module?

**Edit**: The problem isn't importing two objects named logging that clash. I know I can remedy that using import as. The problem is that I can't get to import the builtin python logging module from my `logging.py` file.

Comment: You can import via direct paths, and you can also do `import logging as builting_logging` before doing so.

Comment: @Torxed If I do `import logging as builtin_logging` inside `logging.py` I get the same error.  It's still importing my module instead of the builtin one

Comment: Smack the one who named the module 'logging.py', rename it to 'my_logging.py' and be happy.

Comment: @Phob1a I'm agreeing with HeinzKurt, you simply do not name your own module the same as a built-in and INSIDE try to import that built-in.
There are ways around it, changing the path of where Python imports modules first would solve it, ergo doing `os.chdir('../')` (might have to call another `chdir` funktion but you get the idea before importing the built-in would probably solve it. but WHY?

Comment: @Torxed I just wanted to know if there was a clean way of doing this but I guess I'll have to stick with _logging. Anyway, thanks for the information and the workaround you provided. 

Regarding the reason... Many times, when I want to write a module that performs a task using a third party library the most adequate (short, clear, aesthetic...) name is taken by the library itself (i.e. twitter, logging, warnings, etc.). I hate having to name them twitter_module, log, my_warnings, etc.